# In Lua, should I define a variable every iteration of a loop or before the loop?

Tags: performance, loops, lua, memory-management

Specifically in Lua, will I do any harm by doing this:

```
for i = 1, 10 do
    local foo = bar()
    -- do stuff with foo
end
```

instead of this:

```
local foo
for i = 1, 10 do
    foo = bar()
    -- do stuff with foo
end
```

I mean, will Lua try to allocate new memory for `foo` every iteration? Could the first block lead to slower execution?

Comment: actually I made some simple tests and there was no difference

Comment: Also, see the output of `luac -l` to see the VM code.

Comment: You may find more elaborate answers on this duplicate question: [Is it better to declare a local inside or outside a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31083951/is-it-better-to-declare-a-local-inside-or-outside-a-loop)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go for the safest alternative, which is to use the smallest scope for all variables. As for efficiency, local variables are stored in a stack; no memory allocation is done inside the loop.

Comment: @arkilus Remember to upvote answers you accept. It is done by clicking the arrow pointing up.

Comment: @ponzao I thought that was needed only when there were more than one answer. Anyway, already did, thanks.

Comment: @arkilus You're welcome! (You should upvote answers that you find helpful. The accepted answer is the one that solves your question.)